# Is there a GCC pragma to switch C++11 on and off?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have some headers that fight with C++11 but I'd like to use features like initializer lists in my code. My research says that you can enable newer features at the command-line only, like:

```
g++ -std=c++11
```

What I'd really like is to put in my code:

```
#pragma CXX11_OFF
#include <old.hpp>
#pragma CXX11_ON

vector<int> v {1,2,3};
```

I haven't been able to find such a pragma. Does it exist?

Comment: Does it even make sense to switch on and off C++11 within the same file? That could be tricky to interpret.

Comment: In what way does it "fight" with c++11?

Comment: It's vaguely possible that the compiler could support such a thing, but it would be extremely difficult.  The extern C++ statement does something similar, but I can't imaging compiler writers going to that much effort for every release of the C++ standard.

Comment: @DaleWilson `extern "C++"` does precisely nothing, so not very similar :-) If you mean `extern "C"` that is not similar either, it doesn't turn off C++ features (you can still use exception-specs and references in `extern "C"` functions for example), it just alters name mangling and so prevents overloading. Nothing at all like what would be needed to support the OP's suggestion.

Comment: Even if a compiler supported such `#pragma`, it would be extremely confusing. For example, what should happen if `old.hpp` defines a `struct` with a `std::string` member and then you use that `struct` in your C++11 code. Should the `std::string` member have move semantics? Should (*could*) it even be the same type as a `std::string` from C++11? And why do you want this in the first place? It should be fairly simple to make a pre-C++11 header compile with C++11.

Comment: I would like such a pragma, with a requirement that it appear as the first line of every translation unit. It's a pity we can't currently do `gcc x.cc` and have it use c++11.

Comment: "I want to be able to `#include` Python and Java files into my C++ program, is there a g++ `#pragma` that does this"? Does that sound reasonable? This is the same ask.

Comment: @BrianBi there is a very valid reason to do that. My project started off strongly gnu-ish, so much that we use even nested functions. We are unable to use popular static analysers because of it. To make matters worse, the autoconf enforces -std=gnu99 all over. So I'd like to have standards compliance for a module somewhere after I'm done with all includes making it slightly easier in future to integrate static analysers.

Answer (score 8):

No. Such a pragma does not exist.

You can find a list of all pragmas GCC supports in [§ 6.61 of the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html).

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 2):

`#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-std=c++11"`

This line adds a cpp 11 flag to compiler.

Comment: Perhaps this works on an older version of gcc?  With 8.2 it gives a warning about -std=c++11 does not control warnings.  The warning can be disabled with -Wno-pragmas, but AFAICT code following the #pragma does not get compiled as c++11.

Comment: @PaulBrannan I used it with GCC 4.x to allow partial support for c++11 features.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there exists such a pragma. But turning C++11 on and off during the same compilation unit looks akward to me. Perhaps you should place the "old" part inside a dll and import it then in the "new" part. Then you can only compile the new part with c++11 enabled

Comment: Even in the source directory works for as long you use different build rules.  No different than mixing C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

Since such a pragma does not exist, my suggestion is to rely on make/cmake for picking the "right" files based on a compilation flag.